# What is the weight and dimensions of all items in the full Valve Index kit, unboxed?

Tags: hardware, valve-index

Shipping packages of tech with varying dimensions and weight can mean a lot of money in shipping costs, so for various purposes like shipping, packing and transportation to/from repair, I'd like to know the size (within 2cm on each axis) and weight (within 100 grams total) of the items in Valve Index box unpacked:

- Valve Index headset
- Knuckle controllers
- Base stations
- Cable and breakout box
- (possibly something else required to set up the whole kit to play that isn't listed)

Valve's official store and information pages don't have any information on that. Wikipedia page has only the headset weight referencing gaming news sites. I haven't found reviews weighing anything other than the headset though.

---

Steam support responded with this:

> The shipping weight of the Valve Index kit is approximately 6kg. We cannot give you a more precise answer than this [...]

That is unfortunately not precise enough and doesn't line up with other weight measurements, seems to be an outlier for some reason. I'll post an answer when I get it, I suppose.

Comment: In my experience, fedex, dhl, ups, usps, etc. use "dimensional weight" which is actually a volume measurement, and the density would need to be close to that of a solid cube of lead before the actual weight is used for billing. Certainly some countries have their own rules, but I expect the weight is irrelevant for this item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I measured these weights using a generic unknown brand ~10 USD electronic kitchen scale with 5kg max weight and 1 gram deviation powered by a CR2032 battery.

Everything has been taken out from the original box but what was in its individual black paper boxes was kept in them. Everything measured here is outside of these individual boxes.

The kit is European and comes with both EU and US power adapter prong attachments.

- Headset with cable which is attached to it and with the back-of-the-head rubber support thing: 1248g
- Base station (without stand): 238g ×2 = 476g
- Base station stand (without station): 55g ×2 = 110g
- Controller with the strap attached (it's tiny): 199g
- Mounting screws in a plastic bag for the base station: 9g ×2 = 18g
- All of the power adapters with European power prongs attached + 2 USB charging cables for the controllers: 674g
- All of the empty paper boxes from the wires and adapters (except the manual and its box): 146g
- 3 US power adapter prongs: 78g
- Manual and its box: 115g
- Lens wiping cloth: 5g

## Total: 3069g

---

Because everything has been taken out of the original box (as it's definitely too big and unwieldy for international air travel), the dimensions are variable, and I don't have an easy way to measure them or the total volume if most efficiently yet still safely repacked. Anyone else who knows how can post an answer with that info.

Answer (score 1):

24" x 17" x 9" inches according to [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07VPRVBFF); about **58.5 x 39.5 x 21.6 cm (23" x 15.5" x 8.5")** [says someone on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ValveIndex/comments/cebawm/valve_index_kit_box_dimensions/) (I'm assuming the decimal shows those numbers have a higher accuracy).

The entire set - headset, controllers, and base station - weighs **7.83 kg (17.26 lbs)** boxed, according to a user in [this thread](https://forums.oculusvr.com/community/discussion/76980/the-index-thread-please-keep-to-subject/p22).
The dimensions roughly seem to correspond, based on the photographs shown there.

Answer (score 0):

According to a redditor (Peri0dic_), the box is:

> 24x17x9 in. 16 lbs

Source: [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ValveIndex/comments/c8vhjp/index_package_dimentions_and_weight/)

Comment: When my index comes in the mail sometime this week, I'll verify that this weight and dimension is correct.